# Include a subset of fields in the Auth User session

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

My Users table has a whole bunch of fields, most of which I don't need/want stored in the Auth User session. How do you restrict which fields are stored in the session for the logged in user?

I know you can choose fields of associated models with the 'contain' key, but normally to select fields of the top-level model, you'd use the 'fields' key. But in the case of Auth, the 'fields' key is used to choose which fields to authenticate the user by, not which fields to include in the session.

To give some context, here's my code so far... what would I do to make it so that only the email and firstname fields are stored in the Auth session, as opposed to all fields in the Users table.

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'Blowfish' => array(
        'fields' => array(
            'username' => 'email',
            'password' => 'password',
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: I have no idea what happens, but what if you do `contain => array('User' => array('field1', 'fields2'))` ? Could it be it somehow uses that correctly? So that you manually contain the top level model as well? Maybe that does the trick? (probably not).

Comment: Nup, that'll give you the warning:  Model "User" is not associated with model "User"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've upvoted the answers which were useful, albeit work-around solutions - thanks.

I think the "correct" answer is that there's no way to do this with CakePHP Auth component out of the box, and you have to hack it (eg, using one of the solutions below). I took a look at the `_findUser` method in BaseAuthenticate.php and it confirms this.

In case a CakePHP core dev is reading (DeEuroMarK?), this is probably a pretty common requirement, and I think it's a feature worth having built in.

Suggested implementation: just include the fields you want as extra fields in the 'fields' array - and just assume that every key other than 'username' and 'password' is an extra field that should be included in the auth session. That way it's consistent with other Model find syntax.

Example:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'Blowfish' => array(
        'fields' => array(
            'username' => 'email',
            'password' => 'password',
            'another_field',
            'yet_another_field'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: See if you can find a ticket about it [here](https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/dashboard). If there is none, create one :-) That's the best place to put it.

Comment: In the meantime, isnt there a "fields" key available now?

Answer (score 1):

in the beforeFilter of my UsersController I have something similar as your login.

Then I set a afterLogin function as the redirect

```
 $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'afterLogin');
 $this->Auth->loginRedirectTrue = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index');
 $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display');
```

the login function dus some checks and afterwards redirects to

```
if ($this->Auth->login()){
    // code here
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
}
```

and afterLogin function like this

```
 function afterLogin(){
    $session = $this->Session->read('Auth');
    $user_id = $session['User']['id'];

    // change this to find only the fields you need and then override the Auth.User...
    $user = $this->User->findById($user_id);
    if (!empty($user)){
        $this->Session->write('Auth.UserProfile', $user['UserProfile']);
    }
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->loginRedirectTrue);
 }
```

You should change the findById to suit your needs and then override the Auth.User  fields in the session.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest is to add something like this:

add a contain to your Auth-Component configuration

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize' => 'Controller',
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'email'],
                'contain' => ['Groups']
            ]
        ],
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()
    ]);
...
```

And in you login-action save the user in session:

```
$foundUser = $this->Auth->identify();
if ($foundUser) {
    $this->Auth->setUser($foundUser);
}
...
```

this will add the containing groups to the Auth.User

The is for CakePhp3 - in older versions it may be different.